# How to send push notification to Firebase with localized content?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I migrate application from `OneSignal` to `FCM`. In `One signal` there was a feature that automatically detect the language set on the device. So, when I've sent to oneSignal
`{"contents": {"el": "Ο χρήστης User ζητά πρόσβαση στο κοινόχρηστα αρχεία", "en": "User wants access to shared files}}` it detects device language and chooses proper content from the request. Is there something like that in **Firebase**?

Answer (score 0):

In you case you need to save current language of the Device and send the notification according to the Language.

I have sent the data of Hindi Language in Unicode from PHP back end. Hope this will work for you. but the problem is that char length increases and Firebase has Limit on that

Answer (score 0):

The FCM messaging currently does not provide a way to give various translations for a single message.  You would have to know in advance what the user's language preference is, then send them a message with just the translation you want them to see.  Either that, or you would have to include each translation in the app itself, and send some sort of identifier in the message to tell the app which message to show.